# UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator TfidfVectorizer from version 0.23.2 when using version 1.0.2

Tags: python-3.x

I have a big trained TfidfVectorizer It was created on my laptop with scikit-learn version 0.23.2 When I'm trying to put it to my server where the newest version of scikit-learn 1.0.2 is installed[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRHQc.png) I'm getting warned with the following:

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.